# Почему pdo::execute() не подменяет псевдопеременные?

Tags: php, pdo

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private function attributes($atributes, $isObject=false){
    if($isObject){$attributes=get_object_vars($atributes);}
    foreach($atributes as $key=>$value) {
        if(!empty($value)){
        $keys[]=$key;
        $values[]=$value;
        $props[':'.$key]=$value;
        }
    }
    return [$keys,$values,$props];
}

public function create($arrayOrObject,$tableName,$isObject=false){
    $attributes = self::attributes($arrayOrObject,$isObject);
    if(empty($attributes)){return false;}
     list($keys,$values,$props)=$attributes;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tableName." ( ";
    $sql .= implode(", ", $keys);
    $sql .= " ) VALUES (' ";
    $sql .= implode("','", array_keys($props));
    $sql .= " ')";
    $sth=$this->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute( $props);
}
```

При выполнении запроса в таблицу добавляются записи, но вместо значений вставляются псевдопеременные, как показано на скриншоте ниже, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

У этого кода три проблемы.

1. Псевдопеременные берутся в кавычки, отчего и вставляются как есть.
2. Никакая безопасность, поскольку через имена полей или таблицы вставляй любую инъекцию.
3. Чудовищная переусложненность и путаница. Непонятно, почему данные для вставки берутся из объекта, а имя таблицы - нет. Непонятно, зачем нужно передавать аж ТРИ массива, почему нельзя обойтись одним. Непонятно, зачем перепутан ORM и SQL. Здесь должно быть два метода, один, в классе для работы с базой данных, должен называться insert() и принимать имя таблицы и данные. Второй, должен называться create(), и вызывать внутри себя insert после всех этих плясок с бубном вокруг объекта

Comment: Как можно залить инъекцию в подготовленный запрос? Через какие имена полей. Запрос подготавливается на сервере бд и экранирует все входящие данные.

Comment: @Ипатьев прав надо навести порядок в голове и в коде `self::attributes($arrayOrObject,$isObject)` вызов нестатичного метода как статичного...